# separate db connection.php from db queries

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to improve my non-existing PHP knowledge. To do so I created a MySQL DB and a connection.php file with an SQL query (please ignore SQL injection comments for now, I am aware of it). I trying to figure out, how I can split the connection from the actual query.

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$username = "root"; 
$password = "root";   
$host = "localhost";
$database="test";

$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);

$myNodesQuery = "
SELECT * FROM nodes";

$query = mysqli_query($connection, $myNodesQuery);

if ( ! $query ) {
    echo mysqli_error();
    die;
}

$data = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < mysqli_num_rows($query); $x++) {
    $data[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
}

//echo json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);     
echo json_encode($data);

mysqli_close($connection);
```

My thoughts were to create another PHP file and add `$connection = mysqli_connect (require('connection.php'))` to receive the connection string. Unfortunately, I receive a path error.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavours from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Use this style: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and looks clunky and out of place when used in new code.

Comment: You can't just jam a `require` inside of things like that. You `require` and it imports functions you can call. Inside your database inclusion you'd have a function that returns a valid handle, presumably from a *connection pool* to be efficient.

Comment: *Unfortunately I receive an path error* - it would be useful to see what you have tried to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: You have an error. [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) needs one argument. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping your code as is then:

File `connection.php`:

```php
<?php
$username = "root"; 
$password = "root";   
$host = "localhost";
$database="test";
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);
```

The main file

```php
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
require 'connection.php';

$myNodesQuery = "
SELECT * FROM nodes";
// whatever follows
...
```

Please note that - unless you use a framework - it would be much better if you build your reusable connection class or connection-returning function. And BTW consider using the far superior PDO.

Comment: PDO really is immeasurably better.